# YAT: Save final console output to file

Tags: load-testing, yandex, yandex-tank

I want to save final data from console output to file without intermediate.
How can i do that?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The report module exports all info into html in JSON format. You can get some info from there (cumulative percentiles, for example). You even don't have to modify python code in that case, just add some JS to the page that generates a table.

On the other hand, if you want something more then that info included there, you should implement it in the report module.

What particular pieces of last screen data are you interested in?

P.S by the way, one may create a couple of templates and then provide the `template` parameter in `report` section of `load.ini` to specify which one you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

This screen is good report only for "const" benchmarking. For "line" and "step" ramping the last screen always demonstrates the worst timings and resources. But we are thinking about this feature request.

Comment: tnx, but how we can save this last screen? In code? Can we parse some YaTank log-files after testing and recive this information?

Comment: We'd like to know what is the reason to save last screen. Regression report, human report to tracker, text body for email notification? Please, give us some details, may be we can help you with some hacks.

Comment: We need to customize yours report***.xml (last feature). Ours bosses wanna see text information after pretty charts :)